# Font error when printing with Epson lx-300+ii printer in windows from a java application

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, epson

I created a java application and it is running on windows 7 finely. I created Jasper reports for that software when I try to print a report from Epson lx-300+ii printer letters are printing with out spaces and it is difficult to read.But when i print a document from another software like Microsoft word it prints fine. Their is no errors in my java application.

I think java is not supported by the printer or error in jre.

I have posted this question with codes that i used in jasper soft community [Link to the question](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/845390/error-when-printing-jasper-report-epson-lx-300ii-printer-windows-7-my-java)

What can i do for this?

Comment: "*Their is no errors in my java application.*" That's mightily confident of you. Why do you think that?

Comment: Please help me to find an answer. I have posted this question with codes that i used in jasper soft community [Link to the question](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/845390/error-when-printing-jasper-report-epson-lx-300ii-printer-windows-7-my-java)
@Duncan

Comment: Please ensure your Stack Overflow question is self-contained -  incorporate that same information here, don't just link to another question website.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Epson LX 300 and JRE 7), I've resolved this. Simply I changed the DPI configuration in the `PrinterJob` for the matrix point printer, you need set attribute (`PrintRequestAttributeSet`)

and declare the DPI configuration, for example i have set 120 x 144 DPI, and **solved** the problem.

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attr.add(new PrinterResolution(120, 144, ResolutionSyntax.DPI));
pj.print(attr);
```

Good luck!